# not installed requirements.txt on django project

Tags: django

I am new to programming and this is my first project

trying to start a django project on the server

activated virtual environment

after the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command, an error occurs

```
 Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in  run
        wb.build(autobuilding=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
        self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepa re_files
        ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prep are_file
        require_hashes
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in p opulate_link
        self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requir ement
        all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_ca ndidates
        for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
        page = self._get_page(location)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
        return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
        resp.raise_for_status()
      File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/m odels.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
        raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/beatiful lsoup4/
```

Comment: Without seeing the content of your requirements.txt, I get the impression that you have at typo on the line of beautifulsoup4

Comment: exactly it was a typo, thanks

Comment: but another error occurred during installation,Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: (any versions) .No matching distribution found for Django==2.0.7

Comment: @dev_beginer you should update your question with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok By watching at your problem i saw that there is a typo error in beautifulsoup4 library in requirements.txt file , and in comments as mentioned that u are also facing error in installing django

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: (any versions) .No matching distribution found for Django==2.0.7 –
```

Django above 2 version support only python3 , so try

```
pip3 install django==2.0.7
```

if you have python3.5 and above in your system

Also to see supported versions by pip try:

```
pip install django==0
```

and

```
pip3 install django==0
```

make sure you are not using vpn.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you in? Make sure to have installed everything correctly, make the folders following official docs or maybe a tutorial, make sure to always use the right environment, in which Django has been properly installed via pip (I use pip3) Make sure before to have the latest version of Python supported (I use 3.8.2) and the latest version of pip. Make all the passages again and see what happens. If something goes wrong, be more detailed on what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Going over your problem again, I found that 2.0.7 indeed a correct version.
But in your `requirements.txt` its written as `Django==2.0.7` that should be `django==2.0.7`